# how to show $P_{\hat X}=P_{X}$.where $P_{X}$ is distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal B,P)$, with distribution $P_{X}$. Consider the random variable $\hat X$ on the probability space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B_{\mathbb R},P_{X})$,defined by $\hat X(x)=x$ . Then $P_{\hat X}=P_{X}$.

$\mathcal B $ is $\sigma$-algebra.

thanks for help.

Comment: I think you meant the distribution of $\hat{X}$ under $P_X$ is the same as $P_X$. As it is written, $P_{\hat{X}}$ is the distribution of $\hat{X}$ under $P$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StefanHansen.Excuse me i take a big mistake and also I'm sorry from peter and delete my comment.

Comment: @pualambagher.no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)$ with distribution $P_X$, and $Y$ defined on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P_X)$ by $Y(x)=x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
(P_X)_Y=P_X,
$$
i.e. the distribution of $Y$ under $P_X$ is exactly $P_X$. This is pretty obvious from the definition of $(P_X)_Y$ which is
$$
(P_X)_Y(B)=P_X(Y^{-1}(B)),\quad B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Now, is it obvious that this equals $P_X(B)$?

Answer (score 2):

$P_X$ and $P_{\hat{X}}$ are probability measures on the Borel sets, so we just need to check that they are equal on arbitrary Borel sets $E$.

So $P_{\hat{X}}(E)$ is defined to be $P_X(\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\hat{X}(x) \in E\})=P_X(\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x \in E\}) = P_X(E)$

Comment: First and foremost, what "we need to" stress is that $P_{\hat X}$ does not exist.

Comment: i'm just taking $P_{\hat{X}}$ to be what it's obviously meant to be.

Comment: Read better: $\hat X$ is defined on a space endowed with a measure $P_X$, not the measure $P$, hence $(P_X)_{\hat X}$ exists, not $P_{\hat X}$.

Comment: you're saying yourself you realize what it's meant to be

Comment: ?? Let us keep it simple: (1) Your post is wrong. (2) To rectify one's post is not something shameful or disgusting. (3) Ergo?